# Call stored procedure Using C#

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_CPC`(IN _B VARCHAR(100),IN _G      VARCHAR(2), IN _R VARCHAR(30), IN _D VARCHAR(30), OUT _C FLOAT, OUT _P FLOAT)
```

BEGIN
      //Something Hear
 END$$

DELIMITER ;

I Call this stored procedure by C# flowing Code

```
   DataSet tmpDataSet = new DataSet();

    mCommand.CommandText = "sp_CPC";
         mCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // mCommand.CommandText = "sp_select_all_employees";
         mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_B", "bty-23");
         mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_G", "3");
         mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_R", "9000");
         mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_D", "92");

         mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_C",SqlDbType.Float);
        mCommand.Parameters["@_C"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_P", SqlDbType.Float);
         mCommand.Parameters["@_P"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

         try
         {
             mConnection.Open();
             mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
             mAdapter.Fill(tmpDataSet);

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             strErrorInfo = ex.ToString();
         }
         finally
         {
             mConnection.Close();
         }
         return tmpDataSet;


     }
```

It show following Error 
Input string was not in a correct format.
How can i solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think you did error in the following section

```
mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_C",SqlDbType.Float);
    mCommand.Parameters["@_C"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_P", SqlDbType.Float);
     mCommand.Parameters["@_P"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

change SqlDbType into MySqlDbType

```
  mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_C",MySqlDbType.Float);
    mCommand.Parameters["@_C"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_P", MySqlDbType.Float);
     mCommand.Parameters["@_P"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: Thank you it work now . But Now i face new problem 
After first time call it work when second time again call it show Parameter '@_C' has already been defined. How can i solve it.help me